# Need guidance to create value box output

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity, local-datastore

I'm creating a shiny app with local persistent data referred from [Dean Attali blog](https://deanattali.com/blog/shiny-persistent-data-storage/#mysql) as in section: 1. Local file system (local).

My query is, is it possible to create value box output from this method?

***aggregates data from inputs***

```
formData <- reactive({
  formdata <- c("Associate Name" = input$aname,"Associate Email"=input$aemail,"Client Name" = input$cname,
            "Client Email"=input$cemail,"Ask By Customer"=input$ask,"Remarks"=input$rem ,
            "Date" = as.character(input$date), "Followup Date" = as.character(input$fdate))

  formdata <- t(formdata)
  formdata
})
```

***saves data to csv*** (this creates a separate file every time we submit)

```
saveData <- function(formdata) {
   fileName <- sprintf("%s_%s.csv",
                       humanTime(),
                       digest::digest(formdata))

   write.csv(x = formdata, file = file.path(responsesDir, fileName),
             row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE)
}
```

***loads the data*** (Binding all csv's which contains responses)

```
Data <- reactive( {
  # Read all the files into a list
  files <- list.files(responsesDir, full.names = TRUE)
  data <- lapply(files, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  # Concatenate all data together into one data.frame
  data <- do.call(rbind, data)
  data <- data.frame(data)
  data
}
```

***displaying data in a table***

```
output$responses <- DT::renderDataTable({
input$submit
Data()
})
```

I would like to know if we could create valueBoxOutput to display number of times an Associate name is recorded, number of times a client name has been recorded

E.g: someClient - 10, someAssociate - 5

This is my first shiny app, please help me through this.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it how to do it. the trick is in how we using the reactive function.

```
 output$billing <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(value = length(Data()$Billing[Data()$Billing =="Yes"]),
             subtitle = "No. of RFP's billed", color = "green",icon=icon("money",lib = "font-awesome"))

  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this.  First, you need to make the data you read in using `loadData` a reactive, not a function.  Then refer to this reactive in `output$responses` instead of `loadData`.

Then, create another reactive, `associateClientText` say, that extracts the information you want to display in the box from the data reactive you created above.

Finally, refer to `associateClientText` in the definition of your value box.

Answering your question in the comments below:  here is a simple self-contained example showing how to read multiple csv files and bind them into a single dataframe/tibble.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create some dummy data and write to CSV files
data1 <- tibble(x=rnorm(5), y=rnorm(5))
data2 <- tibble(x=rnorm(5), y=rnorm(5))
write.csv(data1, "data1.csv", row.names=FALSE)
write.csv(data2, "data2.csv", row.names=FALSE)

# Read in test data and combine in a single tibble
allData <- bind_rows(lapply(c("data1.csv", "data2.csv"), function(fName) read.csv(fName) %>% add_column(sourceFile=fName)))
allData
```

Giving

```
            x           y sourceFile
1   0.1663704 -1.53566430  data1.csv
2   1.2903028  0.92808401  data1.csv
3  -0.7523470 -0.54466037  data1.csv
4   0.1036518  0.31038474  data1.csv
5   1.7568151  0.24742720  data1.csv
6  -1.3975505 -0.04481848  data2.csv
7  -0.2800692 -0.67718383  data2.csv
8  -0.8773866  0.18190370  data2.csv
9  -0.9915960 -3.16427113  data2.csv
10  0.6501058 -0.79753204  data2.csv
```

I can't give your more direct help because you haven't provided your own simple, self-contained example.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) may be helpful.

You can copy my `bind_rows` code into your reactive.  Personally, I'd rename the reactive as `loadData` is no longer an accurate description of what it's doing: it's not *loading* the data, it *is* the data.

Comment: `column(width=4, div(id = "form", 
 textInput("aname", "Associate Name",value = ""),     textInput("aemail", "Associate Email",value = ""),
textInput("cname", "Client Name",value = ""),
textInput("cemail", "Client Email",value = ""),
textInput("ask", "Ask by Customer",value = ""),)),
column(width=1),
column(width=4,div(id = "form1",
textInput("rem", "Remarks",value = ""),
radioButtons("bill","Billing",choices = c("Yes","No")),
dateInput("date", "Date", min = "2000-01-01",format = "dd-mm-yyyy"),
dateInput("fdate", "Followup Date", min = "2000-01-01",format = "dd-mm-yyyy"))),),)`

Comment: this is my UI that takes input and I have mentioned the functions that aggregates, save and loads and display the data in the question. It would be really kind to help me as I'm banging on it for a couple of days. I have also changed the reactive as Data() from LoadData() as per your suggestions

Comment: @Geovany would you be able to help me here please